# Empty list error

Tags: java, list

I have the following code

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> reservation = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rs.next()){
        singleList.add(rs.getString("name"));
        singleList.add(rs.getString("type"));
        singleList.add(rs.getString("view"));
        singleList.add(rs.getString("service"));
        singleList.add(rs.getString("checkin"));
        singleList.add(rs.getString("date"));
        reservation.add(singleList);
        // correct line System.out.println(reservation.get(0).get(0));
        singleList.clear();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // wrong lineSystem.out.println(reservation.get(0).get(0));
    return reservation;
}
```

and when i uncomment the wrong line (second System.out) i get an  `Index: 0, Size: 0 error` but if i uncomment the correct line (first System.out) the program runs fine and get the correct results. Why my `reservation` List get empty after the `while` loop?

Comment: You keep clearing the list instead of creating a new list for each record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't clear the singleList, create a new ArrayList instance **within** the loop.

```
List<List<String>> reservation = new ArrayList<>();
// ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()){
    List<String> singleList = new ArrayList<>();
    singleList.add(rs.getString("name"));
    singleList.add(rs.getString("type"));
    singleList.add(rs.getString("view"));
    singleList.add(rs.getString("service"));
    singleList.add(rs.getString("checkin"));
    singleList.add(rs.getString("date"));
    reservation.add(singleList);
    // correct line System.out.println(reservation.get(0).get(0));
    // singleList.clear();
}
```

Otherwise you're clearing the object that was added to the reservation list immediately after adding. Understand that your code continually adds the same singleList instance to the reservation list, and within the for loop fills up this single instance and empties it in a futile cycle.